# “Manquer à” vs “manquer de”

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Here meant in the sense of “to lack / to not have”

I’m trying to say “Manchester lacks a big river”, in the sense that Manchester doesn’t have a “fleuve”.

Someone has told me this should be

> Il manqué un fleuve à Manchester.

I think it should be “manquer + de”. So either “Il manque d’un fleuve à Manchester” or “Il manque d’fleuve à Manchester”. I believe “manquer + à” is only for missing people.

Am I correct or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The most usual ways to say it would be:

> *Il manque un fleuve à Manchester (pour que ce soit une ville agréable).*

and

> *Un fleuve manque à Manchester.*

cf. *C'est en effet qu'il manque un sens aux incrédules, comme à l'aveugle, et ce sens, c'est Dieu qui le donne.* Bossuet.

This is same construction that we use in:

> *Il manque un accent à « ecole ».*
>
> *Un accent manque à « ecole ».*

The next one is more literary and unlikely to be used in a casual conversation:

> *Manchester manque d'un fleuve.*

cf. *Bruxelles manque d’un fleuve.* [Amélie Nothomb](http://cityguide.paris-is-beautiful.com/paris-de-a-a-z/paris-vu-par/amelie-nothomb-auteur-amoureuse-de-paris)

Note:

The following sentence is incorrect:

> *Il <s>manqué</s> un fleuve à Manchester.*

That might be:

> *Il manquait un fleuve à Manchester*.

assuming a big river appeared in the meantime.

> *Il manque <s>d'</s>un fleuve à Manchester*.

doesn't work. That's the other way around.

> *Il manque d’fleuve à Manchester.*

doesn't work either. There is no *élision* before a consonant so *manque de fleuve* is possible:

> *Manchester manque de fleuve*.

Comment: Thanks, so I was wrong!  Why is <Manquer + de> not used in this context?  Have I got the wrong sense of "to lack" ? Are those 3 examples translated as "is missing" in English ?

Comment: *Manquer de* is used in the third form (*Manchester manque d'un fleuve*) but you are correct in writing *manquer* better match "to miss" than "to lack". There is no corresponding verb I'm aware of the can be used transitivally and mean "to lack something" in French.

Comment: @jlliagre : D'après l'Académie, ta première suggestion (usage transitif) ne correspond **pas** au sens de *faire défaut* mais au sens de *rater*, *louper*, *ne pas atteindre son but*. D'après l'Académie (Dictionnaire dernière édition) ta suggestion est incorrecte.

Comment: @aCOSwt C'est bien possible, mais le bon sens ne peut que rejeter une telle interprétation. Ma suggestion n'est peut-être pas encore acceptée ou identifiée par l'Académie, mais elle correspond à un usage courant du français parlé. Tout le monde comprend ce que signifie « il manque un bouton à ta chemise » et il n'y est pas question de rater quoi que ce soit.

Comment: @jlliagre : En fouillant désespérément partout à la recherche de ce foutu usage impersonnel que très peu d'ouvrages de référence consacrent, je trouve deux lignes perdues dans le DHLFqui lui accordent le sens de *faire défaut*. Donc, Oui! Cela me suffit pour trouver régulier ton ***IL** manque xyz à tuv* . Pardon pour le bruit bien inutile que j'ai fait ci-dessus.

Comment: @aCOSwt Pas de problème. Comme tes contributions montrent une très bonne maîtrise technique, j'avoue avoir commencé à douter de ma réponse. Il m'est déjà arrivé ici de considérer comme standard des expressions qui n'étaient en fait que des régionalismes.

Answer (score 1):

Le sens de *faire défaut* (son tout premier sens) correspond à l'usage **intransitif** du verbe *manquer*.

Usage intransitif => pas de COD => Tu as absolument raison. *Manquer **de** xyzt.*

D'où

- Cela manque **de** grosse rivière à Manchester,
- Manchester manque **de** grosse rivière.

Manquer a aussi un usage **transitif** mais il correspond au sens de *louper*, *rater*, *ne pas atteindre son but*.

Ainsi, tu peux très bien manquer ton train pour Manchester, Et... à Manchester, tu ne pourras pas non plus manquer le canal... ;)

On peut lire ces spécialisations de sens dans la dernière édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie.

Même si l'usage est certainement plus relâché que ce qu'accepte l'Académie, je ne crois pas que cela aille au point d'accepter un usage **impersonnel** comme dans la première suggestion dans la contribution de jlliagre.

**EDIT 1** : Pour ce qui est de l'usage impersonnel (non observé par l'Académie), je suis peut-être allé un peu vite en besogne. Le DHLF l'observe au XVIIIe siècle.

**EDIT 2** : Et je présume que *j'ai manqué **à** mes obligations* en ne répondant pas à ta dernière question. ;)

Donc non!... Et vas-y pour la tournure impersonnelle que je décriais ci-dessus... : *il manque certainement des preuves à ma démonstration*.

*Manquer **à*** ne concerne pas seulement les personnes mais et surtout pas les personnes **manquantes**. Mais bien les personnes **à qui il manque** quelqu'un ou quelque chose.
En ce sens, *Manquer* fonctionne un peu à l'inverse de *to miss*.

Tu (sujet) me (COI) manques = I (sujet) miss you (COD)